# select query and same query with having results

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have faced some "complicated" query, like:

```
with q1 as (
select w.entity_id, p.actionable_group, p.error_type
 from issue_analysis p
 join log l on p.id = l.issue_analysis_id
 join website w on l.website_id = w.id
 where l.date >= '2016-06-01'
 group by 1, 2, 3
),
q2 as (
select w.entity_id, p.actionable_group, p.error_type
 from issue_analysis p
 join log l on p.id = l.issue_analysis_id
 join website w on l.website_id = w.id
 where l.date >= '2016-06-01'
 group by 1, 2, 3
 having count(1) = 1
)
```

And tried to

```
SELECT q1.entity_id, count(q1.entity_id), count(q2.entity_id)
from q1, q2
group by 1
order by 1
```

but result provides for me a "wrong" data, cause it's not really contains both counts...

could you please describe the most "cleaner" way to solve such issue without a lot of nested queries?

if it may be helpful - `q2` is similar to `q1` but with  `having count(1) = 1` at the end.

P.S. *Documentation link* will be fine is the answer is simple.

Comment: Presumably you need a join.  Simple rule:  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I've tried to use q1 left join q2 on q1.entity_id = q2.entity_id, but it also fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are, no doubt, getting a Cartesian product and this affects the aggregation.  Instead, aggregate *before* doing the joins:

```
select q1.entity_id, q1_cnt, q2_cnt
from (select q1.entity_id, count(*) as q1_cnt
      from q1
      group by q1.entity_id
     ) q1 join
     (select q2.entity_id, count(*) as q2_cnt
      from q2
      group by q2.entity_id
     ) q2
     on q1.entity_id = q2.entity_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, @Gordon